# Which Graphics driver works smoothly in ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: graphics, radeon, 14.10, gpu-driver

I have AMD radeon graphics card, I faced a lot of problems with graphics drivers from nvidia (like unresponsive black screen) already.

Can someone please suggest which drivers to use without any problems and how to check which drivers are currently installed?

Thank you

Comment: As Nvidia making its code open source , in few days/months all will work fine

Comment: in my laptop in which i among other things use it for games (linux games) and virtualization i have found the fglrx-update driver to work best (although i had some crashes when working with vmware)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has built-in open source graphics drivers installed by default. If you install a proprietary graphics driver, you can have both the open source graphics driver and the proprietary graphics driver installed at the same time, and the operating system will use the proprietary driver instead of the open source graphics driver.

If you have an AMD Radeon graphics card, you should not be using an NVIDIA graphics driver. You should use one of the ATI binary X.Org drivers from the default Ubuntu repositories. These are the video drivers for the AMD Radeon and FireGL graphics accelerators.

There are several different ATI binary X.Org drivers to choose from in the Ubuntu Software Center. To identify the recommended proprietary graphics driver for your hardware open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Wait for a minute or two for the command to scan your computer's hardware. The results should identify the recommended proprietary graphics driver for your computer. Install the recommended proprietary graphics driver using `sudo apt install recommended-driver` where instead of `recommended-driver` substitute the package name of the recommended proprietary graphics driver. Reboot to enable the newly installed graphics driver.

You may also want to install the Catalyst Control Center for the AMD Radeon and FireGL graphics accelerators, which can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.